# $.ready loading of Ads still causing issues and holding up page. Your thoughts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I think this might be a typical issue in which a third party retrieval of asset is holding up my page. So, I doing a lazy load of sorts in an iframe at the very bottom of the page, right before /body tag AND in a document.ready -- YET, some on page (NOT third party, my page) assets are still not loading.. its almost as if they are waiting on EVERY ASSET TO LOAD (these 3rd party assets)...

Is there a way to defer my asset loading -- I am doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arryOFassetSources = ['item1','item2'];
  $.each( arryOFassetSources, function(){
       // here is where I load them either in an iframe or inline.. BUT either way
       // iframe or otherwise -- other content on my page is held up.
       // I basically hostfile a dummy request that hangs to achieve the "delay"
  })
})

</body>

I also tried wrapping the load in a setTimeout ala... with and without closure

$(document).ready(function(){
  var arryOFassetSources = ['item1','item2'];
  $.each( arryOFassetSources, function(){
       (function(s){
       setTimeout(function(){
       // here is where I load them either in an iframe or inline.. BUT either way
       // iframe or otherwise -- other content on my page is held up.
       // I basically hostfile a dummy request that hangs to achieve the "delay"
      }, 500 );
      )(key)
  })
})

</body>
```

Any ideas on loading this content outside the "ready" or "onload" or whatever else that can hold up a page. I am guessing that some of my page is "waiting" on readyState etc.. and thus, waiting on these third party assets.. any way to trick the page or allow the page to complete its load THEN load my assets?

Comment: Do it onload, not ready

Comment: The setTimeout version should be the nuclear option here. What do you see in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools? Are you *sure* it's blocking on the third-party resources and not something else?

Comment: Yeah... once the third party timeouts -- boom, everything loads. There are ready states for for some of the content and that is why it delays. I can't "touch" those resources as they are tenuous at best.. SO, I am messing with the loading of the thirdparty.. I tried "window.onload" didn't seem to help. I will revisit that option. Thanks.